# Magento 2 upgrade error - Upgrading from 2.3.2 to 2.3.5-p1 . Setup:upgrade Integrity Constraint Violation

Tags: magento2.3

I am trying to upgrade a magento store from magento 2.3.2 to Magento 2.3.2-p1

However I am stuck at the bin/magento setu:upgrade section with a SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails error.

So running bin/magento setup:db-schema:upgrade separately to verify also spits out the following

In Mysql.php line 110:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`DBNAME`.`#sql-7d3_8c0ef`, CONSTRAINT `SALES_ORDER_CUSTOM
  ER_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL), query was: ALTER TABLE `sales_order` MODIFY COLUMN `entity_
  id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT "Entity ID", MODIFY COLUMN `store_id` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NULL   COMMENT "Store ID", MODIFY COLUMN `customer_id` int(10) UNSIGNED
   NULL   COMMENT "Customer ID", MODIFY COLUMN `billing_address_id` int(11)  NULL   COMMENT "Billing Address ID", MODIFY COLUMN `quote_address_id` int(11)  NULL   COMMENT "Quote Address
  ID", MODIFY COLUMN `quote_id` int(11)  NULL   COMMENT "Quote ID", MODIFY COLUMN `shipping_address_id` int(11)  NULL   COMMENT "Shipping Address ID", MODIFY COLUMN `increment_id` varcha
  r(32) NULL  COMMENT "Increment ID", MODIFY COLUMN `ext_customer_id` varchar(32) NULL  COMMENT "Ext Customer ID", MODIFY COLUMN `ext_order_id` varchar(32) NULL  COMMENT "Ext Order ID",
  MODIFY COLUMN `original_increment_id` varchar(32) NULL  COMMENT "Original Increment ID", MODIFY COLUMN `relation_child_id` varchar(32) NULL  COMMENT "Relation Child ID", MODIFY COLUMN
  `relation_child_real_id` varchar(32) NULL  COMMENT "Relation Child Real ID", MODIFY COLUMN `relation_parent_id` varchar(32) NULL  COMMENT "Relation Parent ID", MODIFY COLUMN `relation_
  parent_real_id` varchar(32) NULL  COMMENT "Relation Parent Real ID", MODIFY COLUMN `store_name` varchar(255) NULL  COMMENT "Store Name", MODIFY COLUMN `gift_message_id` int(11)  NULL
   COMMENT "Gift Message ID", ADD CONSTRAINT `SALES_ORDER_CUSTOMER_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer_entity` (`entity_id`)  ON DELETE SET NUL
  L, ADD CONSTRAINT `SALES_ORDER_STORE_ID_STORE_STORE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `store` (`store_id`)  ON DELETE SET NULL
```

In Mysql.php line 91:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`DBANAME`.`#sql-7d3_8c0ef`, CONSTRAINT `SALES_ORDER_CUSTOM ER_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL)

Answer (score 0):

By running

```
grep -r -l "SALES_ORDER_CUSTOMER_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID"
```

I was able to narrow down the db_schema.xml file responsible in the db update script when running

> "bin/magento setup:upgrade"

As I was not able to find any relevant information and cross checking a similar error comment I found in researching the issue, I commented the following code in
var/magento/module_sales/etc/db_schema.xml

comment out constriants from 253 to 268

```
<!--
        <constraint xsi:type="foreign" referenceId="SALES_ORDER_CUSTOMER_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID" table="sales_order"
                    column="customer_id" referenceTable="customer_entity" referenceColumn="entity_id"
                    onDelete="SET NULL"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="foreign" referenceId="SALES_ORDER_STORE_ID_STORE_STORE_ID" table="sales_order" column="store_id"
                    referenceTable="store" referenceColumn="store_id" onDelete="SET NULL"/>
-->
```

Then I restart server/ httpd

Finally

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

NO more error. However I believe this is a workaround fix until I am able to get better guidance from magento team.

Comment: Any updates here?

Comment: This saves my day bro thanks! Running magento 2.4.2 and this still works! I don't know the root cause because it is working on the live location.